# Jquery Treetable child node

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to implement the jquery treeTable. I look at the documentation of jquery plugin treetbale.After looking that documentation,I still need to know answer of few question I have regarding the treeTable event.

1)Is there is event which handle the click event on the child node.
2)Is there is paging for the treeTable

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks
Sabbu

Comment: for the first question, do you mean retrieving child node ?

Comment: and for the second question do you mean "load on demand"?

Comment: Yes Rahul and TrueBlueAussie